# Impact of new categories within a feature

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

Let's say that I had a dataset containing a categorical feature column that currently is seen to have 2 categories (A, B). If I were to add 3 categories to the feature (A, B -> A, B, C, D, E), what would the effect on the model be?

I know that since I'm adding new categories, It should be increasing the 'information' for the model to pick up on, making it more robust (right?).

How would I go around testing the impact of these new categories on the model in question? Take a model such as Random Forest as an example.

Excuse me if the question seems to be of a trivial nature.

Comment: Can you explain how you can add categories to the feature? Is this due to some preprocessing step?

Comment: Hi Dan, It's more of a hypothetical question. But in reality it could be something like splitting a category based on some external information. For example take race into consideration, someone is labelled as White, but that White could be split up into different categories based on that person's country of origin.

Comment: I think the practicalities are important here. In the case of race and country, you should just keep them as two separate features - i.e. yes you are adding more information, but it doesn't make sense to increase the number of categories But if you mean you have created the categories by binning a continuous variable and thus have control over the number of categories, in which case I would say leave it as continuous.

Comment: But in your example, you;re really talking about a new feature rather than new categories so standard feature selection techniques could be useful here. Take a look at `permutation importance` for example. Although it is a bit tricky with something like a random forest since the importance tends to get inflated as the number of categories increases.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will likely be specific to your dataset, interactions of the feature with other features, and the choice of model. To empirically test it, I would probably suggest a non-parametric model or one that isn't too sensitive to hyperparameters. You can simply compare the in-sample and out-sample results with the dataset pre- and post-transformation.

It is true that there is more "information" now for the model to learn from, but does not necessarily increase performance since this increased granularity could be either predictive signals or introducing noise. As an example, suppose you added a bunch of randomly generated noise to the feature column - technically there is more "information" but not necessarily the good kind.

Are you doing a classification or regression task?  Are the features ordinal or nominal?

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for the answer! The task is a binary classification and the categories added are nominal.

I will probably try doing some feature selection techniques between the feature before and after the transformation, and also look at the resulting correlations.